# Is there a way to vectorize operations that access multiple elements of a vector?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

Let's say I have a vector of integers:

```
> a<-sample(1:100,10)  
> a  
 [1] 13 23 97 70 63 32 82 31 15 36
```

And I want a vector containing the *cumulative* values of this vector. That is, I want the vector
13 36 133 203 266 298 380 411 426 462

One way to achieve this would be to use a for loop. I prefer doing it using apply/lapply/sapply/..., but the only way I can think of for doing this is:

```
sapply(1:length(a), function(x) {sum(a[1:x])})
[1]  13  36 133 203 266 298 380 411 426 462
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Is there?
(This may have been a bad example, but in general, is there a way to access elements of the list being iterated over, given that you know the position of these element relative to the current one?)

Answer (score 10):

You may giggle, but there's already a built in function for this, see ?cumsum

```
x <- sample(1:100,20)
x

 [1] 32 42 54 79 92 69 96 41 51 22 74 76 86 37 85 99  3 11 17 57

cumsum(x)

 [1]   32   74  128  207  299  368  464  505  556  578  652  728  814  851  936
[16] 1035 1038 1049 1066 1123
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend it over the `cumsum` but `Reduce('+', a, accumulate = TRUE)` would do the trick and is generalizable to other binary operators.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend it over the `cumsum` but `filter(a, 1, "recursive")` would do the trick and is generalizable to other recursive relationships.

Comment: @commenters, I see these other functions being presented. But cumsum is a primitive, doesn't that mean it should be the fastest implementation?

Comment: @Brandon I haven't checked it but I assume you're correct.  In my experience Reduce is nifty but not that fast.

Comment: I did some testing and it looks like cumsum is the winner in terms of speed between the three options.

Comment: @Brandon, no doubt about it. But I thought (and assume the same for @Tyler) that because these alternatives are more general, they would be nice to mention when considering the broader question of *Is there a way to vectorize operations that access multiple elements of a vector?*